# Cropping tool/script for PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, crop

I am looking for a decent image cropping solution, ideally a script that would do the following :

Allow to upload an image (ideally via ajax), crop the image using some jQuery like cropping tool and then save the 'new' cropped image while retaining the image untouched.

Is there anything people could recommend?

Comment: @Matt sorry i'm looking for a widget (I need more sleep I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/) for client-side image processing.

---

#### Edit

It sounds like you might be looking for an image crop GUI for users, rather than a way to programmatically crop images (as I read your question originally). In that case, there are a [variety of jQuery plugins](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20crop%20widget) that provide this; [**jrac**](http://www.lacordeaucou.net/z/jrac/example/) seems to be a reasonably up-to-date one.

Comment: It is to be added to a CMS like system so the Pixastic wouldn't really be suitable for my needs although it does look pretty good tho :)

Comment: I don't really see how it being CMS-like makes a difference. Did you want programmatic image cropping, or a widget that allows the user to crop images?

Comment: Thanks for the links Matt - would you know of any jQuery one's that allow for Zooming & panning (ideally panning with the mousewheel)

Comment: jrac (the plugin I linked in my answer) does zooming, though it does not appear to handle panning. I doubt you'll find a plugin that pans with the mousewheel, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can check here it is good tool

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html